# UICollectionViewController develop and design

Tags: objective-c, ipad

i'm new in objective-c and in apple development.
i need a help in how i can develop and design layout like the picture in the below link:

http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Xcode-Folder.jpg

the idea is that there is a major category of pictures where the users of ipad app will click on the major picture and the sub window will opened below to show the sub image under that category.
each row should shown more than one item in the main category because of that i need to use UICollectionViewController.

i found one sample but they using tableview with only one item per row and below is the link:

https://github.com/cloudorz/lakai

anyone can help please.

Comment: I'm sorry but SO is the wrong place for asking for a tutorial. As it currently stands this question is too broad. Try something and if you have specific issues you will find a community very glad to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Gabriele that this question is perhaps a little too broad for SO. But nevertheless I'd like to offer some advice: try JWFolder on GitHub: https://github.com/jwilling/JWFolders

It's pretty good for what you're after. Basically it takes a screenshot of the collection view before splitting it in half and sliding the bottom half down to reveal another view controller's view.

Look at the code, it's pretty clever how he does it. Cudos to Jonathan Wiling for coming up with it.

Come back to SO to ask specific questions if you have difficulty implementing a collection view using JWFolder. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much Sam, that really what i need to take a look for some code to start with, i really appreciate you help